# ERROR running Appium command: string is not a function

Tags: java, scroll, appium

I'm trying to scrolling on a Android mobile application with Java and trying these codes;

```
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
    scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
    js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

Eclipse is giving this error :

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   ERROR running Appium command: string is not a function Command
>   duration or timeout: 7 milliseconds

[And Appium (version 1.4.16.1) Logs are ;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebIXp.png)

Also I'm using WebDriver.
How can i solve this error ?

Comment: executeScript needs a script to be executed, you give it a string hashmap. I believe this may be your mistake: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

Comment: @Kathara Thanks It might be but these codes are given by appium from there : http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#touchaction
Do you have any option to fix that?

Comment: Can you tell me which line is line 690 in android-controller.js?

Comment: 689 androidController.scroll = function (direction, cb) {
690  cb(new NotYetImplementedError(), null);
691 };

Comment: According to your logs this is where your problem happens...

Comment: What would line 645 in controller.js be?? And where do the lines of code you posted belong to? Because according to your Logs it seems to be executed correctly : "--> POST /wd/hub/session/0e618bca-6003-43a2-99a7-ce467b084150/execute {"script":"mobile: scroll", "args":[à"direction":"down"}]}"

Comment: req.device.scroll(element, direction, getResponseHandler(req, res));

Comment: here: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5065

Comment: The following is the more detailed documentation: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions.md

Comment: Thanks for your help but i analyzed all of them but not have a solution

Comment: I believe your problem is that you use "mobile: scroll" which seems only to work with iOS but not with android. For android you'll have to use TouchAction().press(el0).moveTo(el1).release() for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

SYNTAX : driver.swipe(startX, startY, endX, endY, duration);

Example :

```
driver.swipe(200, 900, 200, 100, 2000);
```